# PHP multiple data type upload form

Tags: php, html, forms, upload

i would like to make form for uploading multiple data with HTML and PHP into database (if needed i can use JS aswell). I want user to be able to fill in post name, add image (or more) and some text.

I found a lot of info how to make multiple input (for example: 3 pictures with 1 submit button) but i didnt find anything about how can i do what i want.

The reason can be my english skills as i believe im unable to ask google the right question.

I would really appreciate any info, even if it's only the right wordt to put on google or some online blog/tutorial on how to do it.
(if i wasnt clear enough, i can add picture of what i want to make)

HTML form:

```
    Title: <input type="text" name="title"><br>
    Category (you can select more): <select name="category" multiple>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select> <br>
    Description:<textarea rows="4" cols="50"> Add your description here. </textarea> <br>
    Image(s): <input type="file" name="images" accept="image/*">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Show us what you want to achieve and what you've tried. And what do you actually want? It's still not clear.

Comment: Edit your question and add that in there.

Comment: there, i fexed my post :)